# How do I use more than one special method ( eg object.__add__(self, other) ) in my class?

Tags: python

Say I had attributes that I regularly wanted to add (and I did so by adding the instances). When I only had one of these sets of attributes that I wanted to add, I used the `__add__` method. 
But now, if I have more than one, do I just make class methods, and not use this particular dunder method  (`__add__`)?

```
class Athlete():

    def __init__(self, name, num_throws, num_games, minutes_played):
        self.name = name
        self.num_throws = num_throws
        self.num_games = num_games
        self.minutes_played = minutes_played

# I was using below method to calculate the total number of throws for 2 athletes
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.num_throws * other.num_throws

# But now I have another addition to calculate the total number of minutes played
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.minutes_played * other.minutes_played

ath1 = Athlete('John', 34, 19, 478)
ath2 = Athlete('Jim', 32, 11, 260)

print(ath1 + ath2)
```

So, in the above case, is there any need to use `__add__` at all? Should I just be making my own methods that add stuff?

Comment: The `__add__` method is not supposed to be called from your code, it is meant to provide support for the `+` operator. I'm having a hard time figuring out what is your question, perhaps you can update it in order to provide an example of what you want to achieve and the problems you are facing.

Comment: You need to decide what + means for this object. Most likely, you don't need `__add__`, and really want to do things like 'ath1.num_throws + ath2.num_throws`...

Comment: While there is no strict requirement to do so, `Athlete.__add__` should return a new `Athlete` object. If you aren't actually adding two `Athlete`s, then `__add__` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the attributes and add them one by one.